# updating task using microsoft graph api giving response of 400 invalid request

Tags: javascript, asp.net, .net, ajax, microsoft-graph-api

From angular2 typescript app I am trying update a Task using Graph API. Following is my request -

```
Request URL:https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/tasks/_1EKXXuN1UGInJ9yVHAjIpYAKuC2
Request Method:PATCH

Request Body:
{
    "createdBy":"f16ca963-29ee-4cdc-834e-8911ff9f628e",
    "startDateTime":"2016-10-31T00:00:00.000Z",
    "assignedTo":"55a899d8-66fd-45e5-900e-85ea01650a03",
    "planId":"W0crdsiJukKWvCOCYrfccJYAEAEg",
    "bucketId":"6szBME9_PkOJO7P4SHZ_hZYAB85V",
    "title":"Where does it come from?"
}
```

Following is the response I am getting back -

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "",
    "message": "The request is invalid.",
    "innerError": {
       "request-id": "c78f8b45-3fd4-4071-9378-6e3f34d8ec11",
       "date": "2016-10-29T19:06:03"
     }
  }
}
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

`createdBy` is read-only, this is likely causing the error.